# Does persistent homology based on variance-balancing ellipsoids give the same simplicial complexes as with spheres?

Tags: variance, topological-data-analysis

In persistent homology estimation the standard approach involves using $\epsilon$-balls. When two balls intersect, an edge is drawn between the points. Faces are formed in a similar way (although the details depend on the choice of Cech vs Vietoris-Rips).

Often variables in a data set have distinct variances. Maybe that is fine for persistent homology, or maybe it isn't. Suppose we wanted to account for different amounts of variation in different directions, I've considered the existence of a couple of approaches.

The first approach is to induce the interiors of ellipsoids instead of spheres. With spheres the metric expands a ball equally in all directions, but one could choose instead to expand the interior of an ellipsoid by $\pm \alpha_1 \epsilon, \pm \alpha_2 \epsilon, \cdots, \pm \alpha_n \epsilon$ along each of the $n$ orthogonal basis vectors (pointing in the directions of increase in each variable). These $\alpha$'s would be chosen to equalize the variances of the variables.

The second approach is to rescale each variable $X_j$ by $\beta_j$ such that the variances are now equalized, and then perform persistent homology as usual with $\epsilon$-balls.

Because an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid is a generalization of an $n$-sphere where the scaling factors are possibly unequal, my thinking is that the above approaches should be equivalent in the sense of generating the same sequence of simplicial complexes.

Are these two approaches actually equivalent in this sense?